# How to prevent a for loop from advancing in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

Is it possible to prevent the `for` loop from proceeding to the next value in the list/iterator if a certain condition is satisfied?

```
lst = list('abcde')
for alphabet in lst:
  if some_condition:
     # somehow prevent the for loop from advancing so that in the
     # next iteration, the value of alphabet remains the same as it is now
  # do something
```

Comment: Do I understand that you intend to cause the current loop iteration to be reexecuted (_value of alphabet remains the same_) until the condition isn't met?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, and that is exactly what i want.

Comment: By the way, there is no need to make a list--strings are already iterable. You can just do `for letter in 'abcde':`

Comment: @Mike Graham: I know that but I wanted to emphasize `lst` which in my case is a hodge-podge of many types!

Comment: Lists are typically used for homogeneous collections. If that isn't what you have, iterating over it can be a bit precarious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can (or should) do this with a regular for list-iterator.   You may want to look at this as a case of a work queue and use a while loop:

```
work_stack = list('abcde')

prev_item = ''
while work_stack:
    item = work_stack.pop(0)
    print item
    if prev_item=='a' and item == 'b':
        work_stack.insert(0,item)
    prev_item = item
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily quadratic.

Comment: Meaning that the time it takes to exhaust this list in the limit is proportional to the length squared, when this could be implemented merely proportional to the length of the list. This is because inserting and popping from the front of a list is expensive. Are you familiar with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation ?

Comment: What you are doing is premature optimization.  I'm making no assumptions about how the list is implemented or whether the size is even an issue (that's not the original question asked).  If the OP wants, he can adopt the solution I offer to a true stack implementation based on a linked list where the inserts are done in a constant time.

Comment: Or you could just reverse the list... Or you could just use a deque...

When the O(n**2) solution is _exactly_ as simple as (or, like in kindall's answer, _simpler_ than) the O(n) solution, it is not premature to adopt the O(n) solution.

Answer (score 8):

What you seem to want is a nested `while` loop. Only when the `while` loop exits will the `for` loop continue to the next value.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for letter in alphabet:
  while some_condition:
     # do something
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `break` to exit the loop immediately, or `continue` to skip to the next iteration of the loop. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html for more details.

Edit: Actually, upon closer inspection, what you're looking for is a rather odd case. Have you considered something like

```
lst = list('abcde')
specialcase = ""
for alphabet in lst:
  if specialcase != "":
       alphabet = specialcase
       specialcase = ""
  elif some_condition:
     # somehow prevent the for loop from advancing so that in the
     # next iteration, the value of alphabet remains the same as it is now
     specialcase = alphabet
  #do something
```

You'll have to modify this to suit your particular situation, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: I do not want it to continue. I want it to pause. The values of `alphabet` at each iteration should be 'a','b','c','c','d','e' for example.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. The value of `alphabet` in that iteration is set to `specialcase` and that value in `lst` is skipped. So, `alphabet` would take values 'a','b','c','c','e' (no 'd').

Comment: wouldn't you be skipping some elements?

Comment: @Manu There, try that. Again, I don't know exactly how your loop is structured, so I'm guessing here. Depending on your needs, that `elif` might need to be changed to an `if`, if you want to check that condition on every iteration regardless.

Comment: @Jared: Yep. That did it. But i'm accepting Dmitry's answer as his stack idea simplifies certain other things in the rest of my program.

Answer (score 2):

Do the loop manually but be carefull not to be stuck

```
>>> i = 0
>>> j = 0
>>> abc = 'abcdefg'
>>> while i < len(abc):
...     print abc[i]
...     if abc[i] == 'd' and j == 0:
...         print 'again'
...         j = 1
...         i -= 1
...     i += 1
a
b
c
d
again
d
e
f
g
```

Another one using `for` but kind of a hack

```
>>> labc
4: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> flag
5: True
>>> for i in labc:
...     print i
...     if i == 'd' and flag:
...         flag = False
...         labc[labc.index(i):labc.index(i)] = [i]
a
b
c
d
d
e
f
g
```

Comment: Nice hack. But this modifies the original list for which i have to make a copy of the original just for this loop. And that doesn't quite cut it for very large lists.